# Keep failing to have coloring in the table, longtable Latex

Tags: tables, longtable, rowcolor

I want to make a color for my rows in different colors. But, when I test it, it keep giving me an error. I don't know what to solve. These are the packages that I used

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newcommand*{\defeq}{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\usepackage{epsf,epsfig,graphicx,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym,fancyhdr,hhline}
\usepackage{multirow, array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cases}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
%\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
 >{\vbox to 11ex\bgroup\vfill\centering}%
 p{#1}%
 <{\egroup}}
```

and this is some of my table code

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{longtable}[h!]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \caption{Comparison different types of ABC sequence.}
    \label{comp_kind_ABC}        \\
    \hline
$m$ &   $k(d-1)$ &   $K$    & $d$ &   Pattern & Name & \makecell{Cycle\\Time} & \makecell{Std.\\ Deviation} & max & min  \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Comparison different types of ABC sequence (cont.).}    \\
    \hline %\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{4.5}
$m$ &   $k(d-1)$ &   $K$    & $d$ &   Pattern & Name & \makecell{Cycle\\Time} & \makecell{Std.\\ Deviation} & max & min  \\ \hline
\endhead
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{10}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape Continue on the next page}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
\rowcolor{green!80!yellow!50} 
2   &   4   &   5   &   2   &   1-1 &   \makecell[c]{Spread \\one-to-one}   &   46.11   &   25.20   &   85  &   12  \\  \hline 
2   &   1   &   2   &   2   &   1-1 &   one-to-one  &   52.64   &   33.46   &   85  &   12  \\  \hline 
2   &   1   &   2   &   1   &   2   &   ABC &   52.95   &   43.01   &   112 &   12  \\  \hline
2   &   4   &   5   &   2   &   1-1 &   \makecell[c]{Spread \\one-to-one}   &   46.11   &   25.20   &   85  &   12  \\  \hline 
2   &   1   &   5   &   2   &   1-1 &   one-to-one  &   46.52   &   32.05   &   85  &   12  \\  \hline 
2   &   1   &   5   &   1   &   2   &   ABC &   46.5 &  36.00   &   112 &   12  \\  \hline 
2   &   4   &   17  &   2   &   1-1 &   \makecell[c]{Spread \\one-to-one    }&  43.55   &   29.54   &   85  &   12  \\  \hline 
2   &   1   &   17  &   2   &   1-1 &   one-to-one  &   43.55   &   31.14   &   85  &   12  \\  \hline 
2   &   1   &   17  &   1   &   2   &   ABC &   43.96   &   32.46   &   112 &   12  \\  \hline 

\end{longtable}
```

and the output is like this

[image]

how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should place `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` before `\usepackage{tikz}`, because `tikz` loads `xcolor` already, but without the `table` option. This should solve the issue already.

Comment: you should clean up your preamble, srcltx, epsf and epsfig are outdated.